# How does Kernel protect Mode Bits (PSW) from being modified by User Program?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, cpu, cpu-architecture

I understand that the CPU distinguishes Kernel Mode and User Mode based on the Program Status Word, but suppose that a User Program was attempting to gain unauthorised access to invoke system calls by gain access into kernel code. What kind of defence mechanisms are there in the CPU architecture to prevent such an exploit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most architectures have privilege levels, in x86 they are called "rings". They are privilege levels assigned to certain places in the address space defining the type of privileged instructions that code in that space can execute.

A program is unable to modify these bits representing the privilege level because they reside in the page table, which is held in kernel space. Any attempts by the code to access this space are trapped by the CPU and captured by the operating system in what is known as a page or segmentation fault depending on the OS you use.

Additionally, a program cannot execute special instructions, say to access the DMA controller that would allow them access to kernel space, because they are considered privileged. Any attempts to use such special instructions by the user code also causes a fault in the CPU which is trapped by the operating system.

So, a combination of memory space protection (ie programs are unable to modify kernel data structures) and privileged instruction protection in a well designed operating system makes the system secure. A program will in general be unable to escalate its privileges because all attempts cause a fault in the CPU which the OS traps. The OS can then kill the offending program.

For a more detailed look into how these all work together in the x86 architecture, I refer you to the OSdev Wiki page on Security:

http://wiki.osdev.org/Security